# Mongodb Atlas cannot view clusters from another computer

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I can log in to my MongoDB atlas but I can't access to clusters from a different computer than that i used for registering. I even couldn't use the other os in my computer to access it. On other computers, i see it as the project is never touched, no data, no new users, it looks just empty, but it isn't. I couldn't find any settings for that nor google did help me about that issue.

[image: Mongo Atlas]

There is an actually a cluster created here, but i can't see it on this computer.

Comment: Are you certain it's the same cluster and project ? Can you try connecting to it via `mongo` shell from both OS and see whether you have access to the information ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar Yeah I'm sure. Today I encountered this problem with another computer, and another account, logged on to the same project but no cluster again. We whitelisted all IP's btw.

Comment: That's quite strange, you should be able to access the cluster as long as you use the right credentials (same account). The IP whitelist only applies to access via MongoDB clients to the cluster itself, not to the Atlas configuration